# How to return a BadRequest from a Controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a form that allow to the user to update his profile. When the form is submitted an ajax request is raised:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (response) {
        alert(true);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //Handle error
    }
});
```

inside the ajax request I need to check if an error happened, if yes, based on the generated error I want display a different exception message.

Now the main problem is that the method called return a `ViewModel` of the updated user, something like:

```
publi class UserController : Controller 
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _repo;

    public UserController(IUserRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUser(UserProfileViewModel updateUser)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       updateUser = await _repo.UpdateUserAsync(updateUser);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Profile");
}
```

The controller have a dependency injection of `IUserRepository` which actually handle the logic to update the user, eg:

```
public async Task<User> UpdateUserAsync(UserProfileViewModel updatedUser)
{
     if(updatedUser.FirstName == "")
        throw new Exception("FirstName not filled");
}
```

as you can see from the example above, if the `FirstName` is not filled, then an exception is thrown.

I want avoid the use of the exception; after some research I found `BadRequest()`, the problem is that `BadRequest` seems missing from `AspNetCore`, seems only available in the `API` version.

Someone have a good way to manage that?

Comment: Is your controller inheriting from `Controller`? In that case, `BadRequest()` should exist and returning it should work.

Comment: @poke the controller inherit from controller, but inside that I'm using the repository to handle the logic, let me update the question

Comment: So the `UpdateUser` method is in a different class? Then of course you cannot use `BadRequest()` as that’s a thing of the controller. I would generally advise you to keep input validation logic within the controller and only pass *valid* data to different services (e.g. your repository).

Comment: @poke nice advice! I updated the question anyway

Comment: There is a thing called a `BadRequestResult` and another called `BadRequestObjectResult` which may be of interest...

Comment: @HereticMonkey if I use it I'll get: `Cannot convert BadRequestObjectResult in UserProfileViewModel`

Comment: If you want your `UpdateUserAsync` to return a user, you cannot make it return action results. You should follow my advice there and have the input validation inside the controller. Since you are already checking the model state, you can also just use [model validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and you’re done. – Alternatively, you could also catch the exception in your controller and handle it there. But you really shouldn’t deal with action results inside your repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@poke and @agua from mars are completely right; you should use model validation. If, however, your validation is a bit more complex and you have to handle it in your service, you can use this pattern. First, create a class that represents not just the data, but an indicator of the service's success in getting the data.

```
public class Result<T>
{
  public bool HasError { get; set; }
  public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

This above is very simplistic; you'd likely want more information.

Then, in your service, change the signature to return a `Result<T>` and add code to create the appropriate one:

```
public async Task<Result<User>> UpdateUserAsync(UserProfileViewModel updatedUser) {
  if (updatedUser.FirstName == "")
    return new Result<User> {
      HadError = true,
      Data = (User)null
    };
  // do something to save
  return new Result<User> {
    HadError = false,
    Data = updatedUser
  };
}
```

And then update your action to receive the `Result<T>` and return the appropriate result:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUser(UserProfileViewModel updateUser) {
  var result = new Result<User> {
    HadError = true,
    Data = (User) null
  };
  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    result = await _repo.UpdateUserAsync(updateUser);
  }

  return result.HadError ? BadRequest() : RedirectToAction("Profile");
}
```

Again, for something like a required property, there are much better methods. I've found the above pattern useful when errors occur in the service and I want to communicate that fact to the controller/action/UI.

Answer (score 0):

As [poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke) told you, use can use [model validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1) by decorating your `UserProfileViewModel.FirstName` with `Required` attribute :

```
public class UserProfileViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I add filters to my configuration to factorize the code.
One to check model:

```
/// <summary>
/// Check api model state filter
/// </summary>
public class ApiCheckModelStateFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly PathString _apiPathString = PathString.FromUriComponent("/api");

    /// <summary>
    /// Called after the action executes, before the action result.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The <see cref="T:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionExecutedContext" />.</param>
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called before the action executes, after model binding is complete.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The <see cref="T:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionExecutingContext" />.</param>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"></exception>
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(_apiPathString))
        {
            return;
        }

        var state = context.ModelState;
        if (!state.IsValid)
        {
            var message = string.Join("; ", state.Values
                                    .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                                    .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));

            throw new InvalidOperationException(message);
        }
    }
}
```

And another one to manage status code depending on exception:

```
/// <summary>
/// Api exception filter
/// </summary>
public class ApiExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter, IAsyncExceptionFilter
{
    private readonly PathString _apiPathString = PathString.FromUriComponent("/api");
    private readonly ILogger<ApiExceptionFilter> _logger;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize a new instance of <see cref="ApiExceptionFilter"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">A logger</param>
    public ApiExceptionFilter(ILogger<ApiExceptionFilter> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Called after an action has thrown an <see cref="T:System.Exception" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The <see cref="T:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ExceptionContext" />.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="T:System.Threading.Tasks.Task" /> that on completion indicates the filter has executed.
    /// </returns>
    public Task OnExceptionAsync(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        Process(context);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called after an action has thrown an <see cref="T:System.Exception" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The <see cref="T:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ExceptionContext" />.</param>
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        Process(context);
    }

    private void Process(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var e = context.Exception;
        _logger.LogError(e, e.Message);

        if (!context.HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(_apiPathString))
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (e is EntityNotFoundException)
        {
            context.Result = WriteError(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, e);
        }
        else if (e is InvalidOperationException)
        {
            context.Result = WriteError(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e);
        }
        else if (e.GetType().Namespace == "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore")
        {
            context.Result = WriteError(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Result = WriteError(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }                
    }

    private IActionResult WriteError(HttpStatusCode statusCode, Exception e)
    {
        var result = new ApiErrorResult(e.Message, e)
        {
            StatusCode = (int)statusCode,               
        };

        return result;
    }
}
```

It returns an `ApiErrorResult` with the error message in the reason phrase:

```
/// <summary>
/// Api error result
/// </summary>
/// <seealso cref="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult" />
public class ApiErrorResult : ObjectResult
{
    private readonly string _reasonPhrase;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ApiErrorResult"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reasonPhrase">The reason phrase.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    public ApiErrorResult(string reasonPhrase, object value) : base(value)
    {
        _reasonPhrase = reasonPhrase;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        var reasonPhrase = _reasonPhrase;
        reasonPhrase = reasonPhrase.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
        context.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = reasonPhrase;
        await base.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
    }
}
```

Thoses filters are set upped in the Startup ConfigureServices method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">A service collection</param>
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(configure =>
            {
                var filters = configure.Filters;
                filters.Add<ApiExceptionFilter>();
                filters.Add<ApiCheckModelStateFilter>();
            })
            .AddJsonOptions(configure =>
            {
                configure.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);            
    }
```

This way I don't need to check if the model is valid in controllers methods:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public Task<IActionResult> UpdateUser(UserProfileViewModel updateUser) => _repo.UpdateUserAsync(updateUser);
```